# mail not sending or receiving ?

Tags: 14.04, email, postfix, dovecot

I configured a mail server on ubuntu 14.04 using postfix and dovecot. When I'm trying to send mail or receive mail then it's not working and GENERATING no error.

**mail log**

```
Jun 11 07:40:18 mail postfix/qmgr[1105]: CF1EC123BD7: from=<info@livewellbd.com>, size=732, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 07:40:18 mail postfix/qmgr[1105]: E8A591239D7: from=<www-data@livewellbd.com>, size=3593, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 07:40:18 mail postfix/smtp[6963]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c04::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Jun 11 07:40:48 mail postfix/smtp[6962]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.29.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jun 11 07:40:48 mail postfix/smtp[6962]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c04::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Jun 11 07:40:48 mail postfix/smtp[6962]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2800:3f0:4003:c01::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Jun 11 07:40:48 mail postfix/smtp[6963]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.29.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jun 11 07:41:18 mail postfix/smtp[6962]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.190.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jun 11 07:41:18 mail postfix/smtp[6962]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400b:c02::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Jun 11 07:41:18 mail postfix/smtp[6963]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.190.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jun 11 07:41:18 mail postfix/smtp[6963]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2800:3f0:4003:c01::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Jun 11 07:41:18 mail postfix/smtp[6963]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400b:c02::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Jun 11 07:41:18 mail postfix/smtp[6962]: CF1EC123BD7: to=<kisorniru@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=18386, delays=18326/0.02/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400b:c02::1b]:25: Network is unreachable)
Jun 11 07:41:18 mail postfix/smtp[6963]: E8A591239D7: to=<kisorniru@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=19458, delays=19398/0.02/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400b:c02::1b]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

It's showing ***`Network is unreachable`***

I'm a beginner. If any one tell me to then it'll help me to go forward.

thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that Postfix is trying to use ipv6.
If this the case then the solution would be disabling ipv6 in */etc/postfix/main.cf* by commenting the line

```
# inet_protocols = all
```

and adding line

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

Then restarting Postfix service

```
service postfix restart
```

Comment: thank's bro for ur answer. But may be I didn't explain my problem properly. I configure postfix and dovecot [By following this one](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-mail-server-ubuntu-14-04/). First time it's working fine . But after some time ( almost 10-12 days later ) later unfortunately my IP was blocked for wanted number of mail receiving. Than I again create my server and setup mail server. But this time when I sending any mail from my abcd@mydomain.com to xyz@mydomain.com or any othersdomain.com then it's showing me sent successfully message but when I check inbox then it's not found.

Comment: Then you might want to point SPF record to your mailserver and check if some user is sending spam through your server, probably your IP is blacklisted

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dynamic IP address, your ISP may be blocking traffic on port 25.  You have two options:

- Use the ISPs relay to send your mail.  This should be the `smarthost` option when you configure `postfix`.
- Configure `postfix` to use the submission port with the required credentials to logon to your gmail account.

If you have configured a firewall, you need to enable outgoing traffic on port 25 to sent email.

If you have a static IP address, you need to get your ISP to set the correct pointer record.  You may need to get them to unblock port 25 for you as well.
You will also need to setup the appropriate DNS records.  This should include `A`, `MX` and `SPF` records as well as possibly `DKIM` and `DMARC` records.  If you don't already have your own domain, you will need to register one. This will get you started on not having your mail classified as Spam.

The items listed for sending from an static IP address should get you started on receiving email.  You may also want to review [Running a home email server using dynamic DNS](https://superuser.com/questions/253230/running-a-home-mail-server-using-dynamic-dns).